# Performing PostGIS calculations without deploying a database

Tags: postgis

I would like to use the functionality that's available through PostGIS for a project, but I don't actually need the database itself.

In particular, I wish to do something similar to this query directly in code, preferably in C# or C++, using some type of library:

```
SELECT
    ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
      ST_Segmentize(ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING(-118.4079 33.9434, 2.5559 49.0083)'),10)
      ,ST_Segmentize(ST_GeographyFromText('LINESTRING(-118.4079 35.9434, 2.5559 45.0083)'),10)));
```

Is it possible to do this without having to deploy and query a database?

Answer (score 5):

Among some native implementations and dependencies to several other libraries, PostGIS binds the [*GEOS*](https://libgeos.org/) library (written in *C/C++*) for many of its spatial processing functions - which itself is one of several downstream projects in different languages of the [*JTS Java Topology Suite*](https://github.com/locationtech/jts); good candidates for simple scripting are:

- [*shapely*](https://pypi.org/project/shapely/) (*Python*)
- [*Turf.js*](https://turfjs.org/) (*JavaScript*)

Alternately you can use [*SpatiaLite*](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index), a spatially extended [*SQLite*](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) (single-file) RDBS, which also binds *GEOS* and provides a similar set of functionality to *PostGIS* within its capabilities.

You will have access to the *SpatiaLite* engine from within a standard [*QGIS*](https://qgis.org/en/site/) installation and covering all supported data-sources (using the *DB Manager*), which as a (I want to say *the*) GIS obviously also provides a wide range of spatial processing tools by itself.

Comment: The Python solution could work, although it would be preferable with a C++ or C# library. Thanks!

Comment: @Q-bertsuit well, all these downstream libraries provide similar high-level APIs, if you prefer *C/C++* then `GEOS` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the [postgis source code](https://git.osgeo.org/gitea/postgis/postgis) to pull out the relevant [`geos`](https://libgeos.org/usage/doxygen/) functions to reproduce it, whether that's worth your time or not is another question.

Comment: That does sound complicated, but at least it's an option if there are no other simple solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in another answer, SpatiaLite has a good support for spatial functions. The list of the functions is here https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html. The native API for SQLite and SpatiaLite is C/C++ https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html but there are many bindings available.

SpatiaLite does not support geography type. If geography is changed into geometry then SpatiaLite can run your query.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the `ST_Segmentize` on the `geography` to make a great ellipse route? Lacking geography support, this would generate vertices in 10 Cartesian degree steps, and the resulting intersection would be wrong.

Comment: You are right. SpatiaLite has some functions that optionally support computation on the Ellipsoid like ST_lenght, but this use case is hard to handle with SpatiaLite and I don't know a simple workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but yes I see that the result is quite different when using PostGIS, so I don't think this would work

Comment: Then just keep in mind for cartesian use cases.